# No files gathered with certain extension every time while using glob.glob()?

Tags: python, search, glob, subdirectory, macos-big-sur

I am trying to search through a list of repositories and extract the C++ files. I am searching through all the subdirectories located in the downloaded repository as well. The specific part I am having the most trouble with is searching the subdirectories.

```
def download_cpp_files(csv_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    df_url = df['URL'].tolist()
    os.chdir('../repos/') # Change into data directory
    for url in df_url:
        try:
            subprocess.call('git clone "{}"'.format(url), shell = True) # Clone the contents of the Github repository
            repo_name = get_repo_name_from_url(url)
            print(repo_name + " downloaded.")
        except:
            print("No such URL " + url + " found.")
        
        target_files = glob.glob(r"~/Documents/open-vocabulary-ros/repos/**/*.cpp", recursive = True)
        print(target_files)
```

Even though there are C++ files located in the Git repositories I've gathered, I still always get `[]` (an empty list) whenever I run `print(target_files)`. I suspect there might be something wrong with the regex I am passing into `glob.glob()`, although I am not sure what other regex to use. I am using a version of Python that is beyond 3.5. I've tried using `pathlib`, specifically the `.rglob()` function, and kept receiving `[]` whenever I run `print(target_files)`. If it matters, I am using macOS Big Sur. How can I fix this issue, and what is the correct regex I need to pass in?

Comment: `glob()` doesn't accept a regex, just a string containing a pathname possibly with shell-style wildcards in it (so you don't need the `r` prefix). That said, I think it's possible the problem could be the initial component of `~` which may need to be preprocessed by calling [`os.path.expanduser()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) on it before passing it on to `glob()`.

Comment: Right, `glob.glob` does not recognize `~`. Tilde expansion is a shell feature, not a property of the file system itself. There is no directory named `~` (or at least, if there is, it's independent of the shell shortcut that uses `~` as a synonym for the current user's home directory).

Comment: Thanks @martineau and @chepner. I used `os.path.expanduser()` and replaced the `~` with `\User\name` and it solved the problem. Such a simple fix!

Comment: greendaysbomb: You should only need to do _one_ of those two things — if I'm understanding your last comment — and it would probably be preferable to be able to leave the `~` in the string instead of hardcoding it, so see if leaving it in and calling `expanduser()` works.